# How to print a graf in the way I need to

Tags: python

I have to print the dictionary(adjacency list):

```
{'ACATG':{'CATGA', 'CATGT'}, 'TGATT':{'GATTA'}, 'GGGAT':{'GGATC', 
'GGATA'}}
```

this way:

```
ACATG -> CATGA, CATGT
TGATT -> GATTA
GGGAT -> GGATC, GGATA
```

and store this into a .txt file.

I tried printing this way:

```
di = {'ACATG':{'CATGA', 'CATGT'}, 'TGATT':{'GATTA'}, 'GGGAT':{'GGATC', 
'GGATA'}}
for v,u in di.items():
  print(v+' -> ', end="")
  li = []
  for g in u:
    li.append(g)
    print(g,end='')
    print(',',end='')
  print('')
```

But there is an extra comma at the end of each set:

```
ACATG -> CATGA,CATGT,
TGATT -> GATTA,
GGGAT -> GGATC,GGATA,
```

And the code is just too long and not pythonic. I would also like to 
 store the printed output into a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for key, value in di.items():
    print(f"{key} -> {', '.join(sorted(value))}")
```

I used `sorted` here to force a deterministic order because `set`s (like `{'CATGA', 'CATGT'}`) are *not* ordered, so you could get a new order with the same data every time you run the script.

Moreover, until Python 3.6 dictionaries (like `di`) were unordered as well, so you should either make sure that your script is running on the latest version of Python (just to be safe) or use `collections.OrderedDict` to force a particular order of elements of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def write_seq(di, file=None):
  for key, values in di.items():
    value = ', '.join(sorted(values))
    print(f'{key} -> {value}', file=file)
```

very similar to @ForceBru but in a function, so you can pass the file if you want.  leaving it as the default will write to `stdout`, or you can do, e.g:

```
with open('out.di', 'w') as fd:
  write_seq(di, fd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
g = {'ACATG':{'CATGA', 'CATGT'}, 'TGATT':{'GATTA'}, 'GGGAT':{'GGATC', 
'GGATA'}}

print(*[f"{k} -> {', '.join(v)}" for k, v in g.items()], sep = "\n")
```

Output:

```
ACATG -> CATGT, CATGA
TGATT -> GATTA
GGGAT -> GGATC, GGATA
```

The `*` in the print unpacks the list we are about to create. The `f` before the quotes means it is a format string literal. `k` will be each key in your dictionary, and we use `', '.join(v)` to put a comma and a space between each element. `sep="\n"` prints a new line between each element.